# Customize .y([yScale]) method in dc.js

Tags: reduce, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to create a Bar chart in DC.js. Here I've reduced avg of a field and want to display that on the y-axis. I have no clue on how to do it. Can somebody help me on this?

```
var dimByChannel = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.channelUUID; });
var groupByChannel = dimByChannel.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    p.bytesTxd = p.bytesTxd + v.bytesTxd;
    p.avg = (p.bytesTxd/total)*100;
    p.count = p.count + 1;
    return p;
}
function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    p.bytesTxd = p.bytesTxd - v.bytesTxd;
    p.avg = (p.bytesTxd/total)*100;
    p.count = p.count - 1;
    return p;
}
function reduceInitial() {
    return {
    bytesTxd: 0,
    avg: 0,
    count: 0
    };
}
```

I've calculated `total` using `reduceSum()`. Till now everything is good. Now how to show the reduced `avg` on y-axis?

```
chanUtil
    .dimension(dimByChannel)
    .group(groupByChannel)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.channelUUID; })))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    //.y(d3.scale.linear().domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.avg; })))
    .yAxisLabel("Utilization %");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `.y()` is rather deceptively (or vaguely) named: that one is for the scale, which maps chart coordinates to physical coordinates.

What you want here is [`.valueAccessor()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#valueaccessorvalueaccessorfunction):

```
.valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.avg; })
```

Comment: Thanks.. I probably didn't go through `.valueAccessor()` in API. Of course, it was difficult to understand completely. You must be a master of `dc.js` and `crossfilter.js`, I find ur answers quite often in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm the current maintainer but not the original author. It's true, there isn't comprehensive documentation. Most people start from the [annotated stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) and the other examples.